# Show selection at the top of a table

Tags: filter, data-tables, multi-selection

I am designing a table that contains a series of items, each item has a series of associated details (name, number, group, etc) that are displayed in several columns; each column has a filter in the header, so that the user can filter and sort the items comfortably, and thus quickly find and select what he/she is looking for.

[image: table]

---

[image: table2]

The table allows multiple selection of items, and then actions can be performed in block to the selected items, through an action panel.

Some stakeholders have thought that it may be useful to add an option through which the selected items appear at the top of the table, in order to have all the selection visually grouped in the same area, and also for example to be able to select items from different pages and at the end of the selection, return to page 1 to see all the selection made.

It seems to me that it can be useful to add this option, but I also think that if it is not well designed it can be confusing, for example, the fact of having to return to page 1 to view all the selected items, and also the behavior of the table if for example a second filtering is performed with a selection made.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "...select items from different pages..." — How does someone get from one page to another?

Comment: There is a paginator at the top right (not in the image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a sort option for the checkbox column:

[image: sort selected]

OR

[image: sort checkbox]

Comment: Thank you! That seems to partially solve the problem. But I'm still thinking about what should happen if a filter is applied after a selection has been made. Would it be more natural for the selection to be undone...(losing the selection) or maybe apply the filter keeping the selection, even though some items may no longer be seen, and display a message that there are selected items that are not being displayed due to the filter application?

Comment: "...apply the filter keeping the selection..." —Yes.

Comment: Do your stakeholders show they need or wish to know they have selected items that do not fall within the filter they applied? If not, I suggest don't bother with the selected items that are not listed, BUT keep track that they are selected in case someone undoes their filter.

Comment: Yes, indeed, they would like somehow that the selection is "isolated" from the filter; to continue filtering the rest, to find the rest of items that they need, and that when selecting these, they are added to the list of selected to which to apply the corresponding action.

But I don't have very clear how to do it so that it is clear to understand for all the users.

I think that some users may find it strange to apply a filter and that some items (the selected ones) are not affected by the filter. 

What do you think?

Comment: I thought maybe to add a switcher at the top of the table saying something like: "exclude selection from filters" or something like that, so if it is activated, the selected items are not affected by the filters.

Comment: "Yes, indeed, they would like somehow that the selection is "isolated" from the filter..." — I see—I like it. Although I suggest reverse the perspective—have an option "**Include selected items** along with filtered results" that is selected by default, but can be unselected to indicate they no longer need those selections.

Comment: "...find it strange to apply a filter and that some items...are not affected by the filter..." Indeed. The first thing that comes to mind is add a filter result column you can flag the records in the list that are a result of the filter. That may even be persistent, even when someone performs multiple filter/select operations, the previous filter flags remain, and aggregate for each record.